# Find majority element in an array

Tags: java, arrays, hashmap

solution 1: no hashmap

```
class Solution {
    public int majorityElement(int[] nums) {
        Arrays.sort(nums);
        return nums[(nums.length/2)];
    }
}
```

Solution 2: HashMap

```
class Solution {
    public int majorityElement(int[] nums) {
        for(int i:nums){
            if(hm.containsKey(i)){
                int cnt=hm.get(i);
                if(cnt+1>nums.length/2) return i;
                hm.replace(i,cnt+1);
            }
            else{
                if(1> nums.length/2) return i;
                hm.put(i,1);
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Which solution is faster and why ? what is the complexity of each solution?

Question:

Given an array of size n, find the majority element. The majority element is the element that appears more than ⌊ n/2 ⌋ times.

You may assume that the array is non-empty and the majority element always exist in the array.

Comment: This question `The majority element is the element that appears more than ⌊ n/2 ⌋ times.` and solutions are not matching

Comment: `if(1> nums.length/2) return i;` this is not right...

Comment: This appears to be a homework question - have you read through the section on asking homework questions here: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822) With that in mind, what have you tried or how have you tried to answer your questions about solution speed and complexity?

Answer (score 1):

I think solution #2 using `HashMap` is faster.

In solution #1, you are sorting the whole array, which will have a worst case complexity of about O(nlogn).

While in solution #2, you are just doing a single pass of the array, so the complexity is O(n). You are even breaking (returning) as soon as you found an element having count as half of the number of elements. Although this solution might take some extra memory, it will be faster.

Note that I am ignoring the time taken by `containsKey()`, `get()`, etc. because an Integer key would provide constant random access. Same is the case with array element access, like `nums[index]`.